# How to automatically collapse code in RShiny app server (reactives, renders, etc)

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, code-folding

I am working with a very large RShiny app and want to take advantage of code folding to organize the server.R file in this application. However, when I use the code-fold hotkey, it does not fold the various elements defined in the server (the reactive, render, etc. elements).

I'd like to be able to take this

```
# observe some things
observe({
  query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
  if (!is.null(query[['tab']])) {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebarMenu", selected = query[['tab']])
  }
  if (!is.null(query[['player']])) {
    updateSelectInput(session, "profile", selected = query[['player']])
  }
})


# Lots of "reactive" data fetching functions 
league_stats <- reactive({
  get1 <- fetch('yada')  
  return(get1)
})

# another reactive
shooting <- reactive({
  get1$SHORT_MR_MADE<-sum(get1$short_mr_fgm,na.rm=T)
  ...
  ...
)}
```

and collapse it into this (or something like this) by just hitting the code-collapse hotkey.

```
# observe some things
observe({--})

# Lots of "reactive" data fetching functions 
league_stats <- reactive({--})

# another reactive
shooting <- reactive({--})
```

Is this possible to do with R / RStudio? I would like to avoid using the 4 # signs `####` above the function to code fold, as this will hide the `shooting <- reactive({--})` strings as well, however I'd like to still have show (and just hide the code inside).

I will oftentimes wrap code in functions since functions collapse, however I cannot wrap RShiny reactive elements in functions (or, i'm not sure how), as it seems like this breaks the app.

Answer (score 1):

Shiny reactives behave as other functions, but you need to take care about passing to them the `input`, `session` or other `reactives` (as `function`, not as value) they need.

As an illustration :

```
library(shiny)

generateUI <- function() {fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  textOutput('counter')
)}

ui <- generateUI()

myobserver <- function(input,counter) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    cat('Clicked \n')
    counter(counter()+1)
  })
}

myformater <- function(counter) {
  renderText(paste('count is',counter()))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  myobserver(input,counter)
  output$counter <- myformater(counter)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Collapsed code :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without creating them as functions is to put an identifier above each code chunk:

```
library(shiny)
# Generate UI ----
generateUI <- function() {fluidPage(
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  textOutput('counter')
)}

ui <- generateUI()

# Observer ----
myobserver <- function(input,counter) {
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    cat('Clicked \n')
    counter(counter()+1)
  })
}

# Formatter ----
myformater <- function(counter) {
  renderText(paste('count is',counter()))
}

# Server ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  myobserver(input,counter)
  output$counter <- myformater(counter)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You will then be able to collapse code segments in between the two identifiers to view as shown below:

[image]